# Drawing in milimeter unit

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, drawing

I'm working in a project which need some drawing and I got a question.
How to draw something in milimeter unit. I've this code but the result seem not be accurate. I used a ruler to measure on the screen and it's about 38mm. Here is the code:

```
e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 10, 10, 50, 10);
```

Please give me a guide, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to draw something in "real world" units, you will need to know several things:

- Resolution used
- *Physical* DPI of the attached display (that implicitly includes knowledge of the physical screen size)

A simple example:

Two computers have the same resolution and the same DPI settings inside windows.
But, one computer has a 13 inch display attached, the other computer has a 27 inch display attached.
That means that the physical pixel density on the smaller display is much higher, i.e. more pixels per millimeter.

So, a line that is 10 millimeters long would need to contain about double the number of pixels on the small display.

Comment: so I have to convert pixel to inch and then to milimeter manually?

Comment: @SmartGoat: Yes. But I don't think you really can do that. Because you need the *physical* pixel density (DPI) of the monitor you want to display that on. I don't think you can know that, because it totally depends on the physical size of the display. And I doubt that every 20 inch display is exactly 20 inch. Even if it were, you would need to know that size. And what would you do on machines with multiple monitors of different size?

Comment: Thanks, for long, I believe that the ruler in MS Word is accurate. I've just measure the Word's ruler. And that desmonstrate that I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel is right, "worst case scenario" you have to get desktop resolution and screen (monitor) DPI and calculate the unit yourself.
But on the first go I'd try using TransformPoints: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k42sdzey.aspx

Comment: Mark, it's not about monitor DPI. It's about physical pixel density, i.e *physical* DPI. See my comment to my answer for further details.